# Signature mismatch in Payfort payment integration

Tags: android, payfort

I am integrating Payfort payment gateway in my android application. I am using FORT SDKv1.2.
In the post url for creating token, I am getting error "signature mismatch" always.

Can anybody tell me which signature is to be used?

url - https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi

Comment: signature must be generated based on the request parameters and specification

Comment: I am doing exactly like this..but always getting same result

Comment: Also , api give signature value in response.. I also use that signature value but again getting smae result.

Comment: show what are your parameters in the request and payfort response

Comment: signature in the response is not for sending request back. It is just for you to verify if the response is coming back from correct source. You can generate signature from response fields and verify that with returned signature.

Comment: Can any one send the format of generate signature?

Comment: Please check this question and answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53933570/signature-mismatch-error-on-payfort-sdk-token-generation

Answer (score 6):

Let me guide you step by step:

***NOTE***: The following is an example for the **Merchant Page 2.0** request signature generation:

> **Step 1:** Add these variables on top of your file

```
private final static String KEY_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER = "merchant_identifier";
private final static String KEY_SERVICE_COMMAND = "service_command";
private final static String KEY_LANGUAGE = "language";
private final static String KEY_ACCESS_CODE = "access_code";
private final static String KEY_MERCHANT_REFERENCE = "merchant_reference";

private final static String MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER = "YOUR_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER";
private final static String ACCESS_CODE = "YOUR_ACCESS_CODE";
private final static String SHA_TYPE = "SHA-256";
private final static String SHA_REQUEST_PHRASE = "YOUR_SHA_REQUEST_PHRASE ";
private final static String LANGUAGE_TYPE = "en";
```

Make sure you are using your given **MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER**, **ACCESS_CODE** and **SHA_REQUEST_PHRASE** by Payfort.

> **Step 2:**  Create a string

```
String concatenatedString = SHA_REQUEST_PHRASE +
                KEY_ACCESS_CODE + "=" + ACCESS_CODE +
                KEY_LANGUAGE + "=" + LANGUAGE_TYPE +
                KEY_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER + "=" + MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER +
                KEY_MERCHANT_REFERENCE + "=" + YOUR_MERCHANT_REFERENCE +
                KEY_SERVICE_COMMAND + "=" + "TOKENIZATION" +
                SHA_REQUEST_PHRASE;
```

Here **YOUR_MERCHANT_REFERENCE** is your unique merchant reference. It should be unique for every request

> **Step 3:** Create a function to generate SHA-256 type signature from your
>   concatenatedString in Step 2

```
private String createSignature(String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA_TYPE);
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        return String.format("%0" + (messageDigest.length * 2) + 'x', new BigInteger(1, messageDigest));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

> **Finally**
>   Call the createSignature function by passing your concatenatedString in Step 2.

```
String signature = createSignature(concatenatedString);
```

Comment: Do I have to include only five parameters to generate the signature in case of Apple Pay?
https://docs.payfort.com/docs/apple-pay/build/index.html#before-starting-the-integration-section-in-the-api

Comment: He is talking about merchant  page 2 requests parameters

Comment: @AbhishekShukla For request parameters change it according to your need which will be mentioned in PayFort document

Comment: @RamiSalim is right i gave you example for merchant page 2

Answer (score 1):

Change 'merchant_reference' value to one you didn't use before. It should be unique. I had the same trouble and it was fixed using it.

Sort your keys in array alphabetically, add before and after the secret phrases and then encrypt the string using your algorythm.

After it, you can use it in your requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem and found there is problem in algorithm i hvae used while generating signature. So plz check sequence of parameters while generating signature. and check for algorithm which u have setup in account and use same algorithm while generating signature

Answer (score 0):

also make sure that the merchant reference is alphanumric and if you want to add special chars you can only add . _ -

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.payfort.com/docs/in-common/build/index.html#create-signature-value) you can find how to generate **signature**.

I was facing this `signature mismatch` error due to concatenating wrong **SHA Request Phrase** to the start and end of the signature.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem and found there is problem in integration settings.Just login into your payfort account and goto payment integration settings then your merchant reference id place check 
   SHA Type is SHA-256 and SHA Response Parse ,SHA Request Parse will same text.This same text added to your accesscode and sdk-token in the source code parameters.Please check below image once.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
 String concatenatedString = SHA_REQUEST_PHRASE +
                KEY_ACCESS_CODE + "=" + ACCESS_CODE +
                KEY_DEVICE_ID + "=" + device_id +
                KEY_LANGUAGE + "=" + LANGUAGE_TYPE +
                KEY_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER + "=" + MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER +
                KEY_SERVICE_COMMAND + "=" + SDK_TOKEN +
                SHA_REQUEST_PHRASE;
```

Then, pass this concatenated string in below method,

```
  private static String getSignatureSHA256(String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA_TYPE);
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        return String.format("%0" + (messageDigest.length * 2) + 'x', new BigInteger(1, messageDigest));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Use below code to get Signature,

```
            String signature = getSignatureSHA256(concatenatedString);
```

Happy Coding :)